# Как правильно описать конструктор копирования?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, конструктор-копирования

**Файл matrix.txt**

- 4
- 5 9 2 4
- 4 5 7 8
- 2 4 1 7
- 1 2 4 8

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream f1("matrix.txt");
class matrix
{
    public:
        int a[10][10], sizeeArray;
        matrix(int n)
        {
    //===============================================
            int **a = new int* [n];
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                a[i] = new int [n];
    //===============================================
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                    f1 >> a[i][j];
            cout << endl;
    //===============================================
            for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
                    cout << a[i][j] << " ";
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << "The constructor of the matrix class was called";
        }


        matrix(const matrix &otherOb)
        {
            int **b = new int* [otherOb.sizeeArray];
            for (int i = 1; i <= otherOb.sizeeArray; i++)
                b[i] = new int [otherOb.sizeeArray];

            for(int i = 1; i <= otherOb.sizeeArray; i++)
                for(int j = 1; j <= otherOb.sizeeArray; j++)
                    b[i] = otherOb.a[i][j];
            cout << endl;
            cout << "The copy constructor was called";
        }


        ~matrix()
        {
        //===========================================================================
            for(int i=1; i<=sizeeArray; i++)
                delete [] a[i];
            delete [] a;
            cout << "\nThe destructor of the matrix class has been called";
        }
};


int main()
{
    int n;
    f1 >> n;
    matrix m1(n);
    //matrix m2(n);
    m1.sizeeArray = n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Написана полная бессмыслица. О конструкторе копирования тут рано думать - переделывать надо все.

Comment: В вашем случае будет правильным переопределить конструктор копирования. А точнее запретить.  "MyClass(const MyClass& mc) = delete;" Советую сделать так пока вы не сильны в ООП и вас затрудняет самому написать конструктор копирования. Так же советую на моем примере написать переопределение конструктора присваивания. Поймите как в принципе работает экземпляр класса.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, не понятно следующее объявление члена класса

```
int a[10][10]
```

так как оно нигде не используется.

В конструкторах вы имеете дело с локальными указателями, а не с объявленным членом класса в виде массива как, например,

```
int **a = new int* [n];
```

Кроме того, члены данных вашего класса следует сделать закрытыми.

Например,

```
class matrix
{
private:
    int **a, sizeeArray;
public:
    //...
```

К тому же индексация массивов начинается с `0`, а не с `1`.

Если вы все же выберите вариант, когда членом класса является не массив, а указатель типа `int **`, то конструктор копирования может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
matrix( const matrix &otherOb ) : a( nullptr ), sizeeArray( otherOb.sizeeArray )
{
    this->a = new int *[sizeeArray];

    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeeArray; i++ )
    {
        this->a[i] = new int[sizeeArray];
        std::copy( otherOb.a[i], otherOb.a[i] + sizeeArray, this->a[i] );
    }
}
```

Имейте в виду, что в этом случае вам нужно будет также определить копирующий оператор присваивания и деструктор.